# Bokeh vbar_stack bars don't re-sort after filtering the data source

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

I have a vbar_stack chart that I am updating with CheckboxGroup selections. When I change the accounts being selected, the data does change, but the chart doesn't re-sort. How can I make the accounts re-sort in descending order?

Right now, I am using this code for the CheckboxGroup onchange command. The custom_make_dataset function does re-sort the filtered dataset.

```
def custom_make_dataset(df, accounts):

    remove_accounts = [i for i in df["acc"].unique() if i not in accounts]

    new_df = df \
            .groupby(["acc","product"])["cost"] \
            .sum() \
            .reset_index() \
            .pivot(columns="acc", index="product", values="cost") \

    for account in remove_accounts:
        new_df[account] = 0

    new_df["Total"] = new_df.sum(axis=1)
    new_df.sort_values(by="Total", ascending=False, inplace=True)
    del new_df["Total"]

    return ColumnDataSource(new_df)

def update_checkbox(attr, old, new):
    accounts_to_plot = [account_selection.labels[i] for i in account_selection.active]
    new_src = custom_make_dataset(df,accounts_to_plot)
    source.data.update(new_src.data)

account_selection = CheckboxGroup(name="Customer Accounts", labels=initial_accounts, active = [i for i,j in enumerate(initial_accounts)])
account_selection.on_change('active', update_checkbox)
```

[Full Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvlxh.png)
[After 1 Account Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrEJC.png)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. While I was updating the data, I wasn't updating the x-axis itself. You can put something like this in the onchange command to update the plot x-axis.

p.x_range.factors = (new_src.data['product'])

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bokeh is using the dataframe index to determine on which x position the values are placed.

Try resetting your `new_df` index before returning the new `ColumnDataSource`.
`new_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: That didn't work. I also checked the ColumnDataSource using `ColumnDataSource(new_df).data` and the values are sorted correctly in the data store.